# Project Manager configuration file. Restart service id to 1

Tags: strongloop

I made several deployments using slc ctl deploy, this makes the service id to increment.

Now I'm trying to use arc, but there is a restriction that arc can only manage Project Manager applications with Service Id 1.

I'm trying to deploy a service to Project Manager with Service Id 1 but I'm no being able.

Is there any file or command to (re)set the Service Id for new deployments or for existing deployments?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to uninstall pm and install it again and I found the answer. I guess there will be other more "supported" way.

The file is /var/lib/strong-pm/strong-pm.json. Make a backup of this file!

But the important thing is to stop the pm service before edit it.

These are the steps I have followed:

List the applications deployed with "slc ctl ls", if there are any remove them with "slc ctl remove ".

Stop the service "sudo /sbin/initctl stop strong-pm".
Edit the file /var/lib/strong-pm/strong-pm.json with sudo privileges.

```
{
  "ids": {
    "User": 1,
    "AccessToken": 1,
    "ServerService": 1,
    "Group": 1,
    "Executor": 2,
    "ServiceInstance": 1,
    "ServiceProcess": 1,
    "ServiceMetric": 1,
    "AgentTrace": 1,
    "ExpressUsageRecord": 1,
    "ProfileData": 1,
    "InstanceAction": 1
  },
  "models": {
    "User": {},
    "AccessToken": {},
    "ServerService": {},
    "Group": {},
    "Executor": {
      "1": "{\"address\":\"localhost\",\"hostname\":\"ubuntu\",\"metadata\":{},\"id\":1}"
    },
    "ServiceInstance": {},
    "ServiceProcess": {},
    "ServiceMetric": {},
    "AgentTrace": {},
    "ExpressUsageRecord": {},
    "ProfileData": {},
    "InstanceAction": {}
  }
}
```

Save and start the pm service again "sudo /sbin/initctl start strong-pm".

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to set port with 3001

```
slc ctl env-set myapp PORT=3001
```